# How include CordApp to Gradle project?

Tags: corda

I want to connect to the Corda node using RPC. How can I include the CordApp Gradle project to my Spring one?

I found this ([obligation-cordapp](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp)). But here the client is inside the Corda project and in my case, I have two Gradle projects. One CordApp and other Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See sample spring-webserver. see this link
https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver

This can help you what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is ok but still, I think this way I can only use inside CorDapp. Can I ask you to explain how do you see it?

Comment: I have used springBoot API server on a separate VM as well as a service. You can then connect to a corda node using RPC and call various flows or execute vaultQueries. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can include the cordapp and states jar in your spring client by adding the below lines inside the build.gradle file under dependencies

```
  cordapp "org:your-cordapp:$your_version"
  compile "org:your-contract-states:$your_version"//if needed
```

Comment: Can I ask for an example?